# Functional Programming function cadence

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, software-design

I have a software project where I have a bunch of functions that check one thing. So the code looks like this:

```js
const isRed = color => color === 'red;;
const isBlue = color => color === 'blue';

function whichColour(color){
  if(isRed(color){
    return 'X'
  }
  
   if(isBlue(color){
    return 'Y'
  }

}
```

This is just an example and the application has ALOT more of these functions that check one thing. I thought having all of these functions, that do one thing, is in accordance with functional programming paradigms.

However recently I have been thinking it would be better to do this:

```js
const isColor = (color, targetColor) => color === targetColor;

function whichColor(color){
  if(isColor(color, 'red'){
    return 'X'
  }
  if(isColor(color, 'blue')){
    return 'Y'
  }
}
```

I think they are both just as readable, as you can see the desired value, and it would save a lot of space because I truly do have a lot of these little functions. However, I am not sure which is actually better.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Unless you *really* like how it reads, `isColor` is just `===`. `color === "red"` is pretty readable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better approach is the one that reduces the amount of duplicated code in general, since it leaves the code neater and more approachable most of the times. So the second way is the one that I would go with in this case. The only change that I would suggest to do is to name the method `sameColor` or `colorMatch`.

Answer (score 1):

```
const colors = {
    red: 'X',
    blue: 'Y',
    green: 'Z',
    // a lot of other colors
}

function whichColor(color) {
    return colors[color]
}
```

Comment: This. +100 from me, there are cases where constructs other than using functions are preferred.